# Pydantic: computed field dependent on attributes parent object

Tags: python, python-3.x, pydantic

As you can see from my example below, I have a computed field that depends on values from a parent object.

A parent has children, so it contains an attribute which should contain a list of Children objects. But I want a computed field for each child that calculates their allowance based on the parent object.

The below example is the best solution I could think of, but I'm unsure about my approach, and I would appreciate your advice on whether there is a better solution than referencing both objects in each other.

```
from __future__ import annotations
from pydantic import BaseModel, computed_field, ConfigDict

class Parent(BaseModel):
    model_config = ConfigDict(validate_assignment=True)
    earns_monthly: int = 3000

    @computed_field
    @property
    def available_for_allowance(self) -> int:
        return self.earns_monthly * 0.05

class Parents(BaseModel):
    model_config = ConfigDict(validate_assignment=True)
    parents: list[Parent] = []
    children: list[Child] = []

class Child(BaseModel):
    model_config = ConfigDict(validate_assignment=True)
    parents: Parents = None

    @computed_field
    @property
    def monthly_allowance(self) -> int:
        monthly_allowance: int = 0
        if self.parents:
            for parent in self.parents.parents:
                monthly_allowance += parent.available_for_allowance
        return monthly_allowance

mom = Parent()
dad = Parent()
child = Child()

parents = Parents(
    parents=[mom, dad],
    children=[child]
)

# Now the parents object is set, also store this one in the 
# child or children objects, so the allowance can be computed.
child.parents = parents

for child in parents.children:
    print(child.monthly_allowance)
```

It just feels weird to have circular references (children attributes in Parents links to the child object and the parents attribute in the child object refers to the parents object again):

```
Parents.children -> child object
Child.parents -> parent object

# If I'd do this, it would just result in an infinite loop:
# Obviously the parents attribute is just for back referencing, 
# to get access to certain attributes, but still, 
# you get my point.
def getchildren(parents):
    for child in parents.children:
        getchildren(child.parents)
print(getchildren(parents))
```

That's the reason I'm asking if there is any advice that this is totally the right way, or there are better ways I'm not familiar of. You're never too old to learn I guess.

Comment: lftm - i rem hibernate ORM ( java ) many-to-many relationships modelled more or less like that - if you code the recursive search method correctly with an exit condition it wont 'infinite loop'

Comment: Yeah, I guess it just feels wrong. But that might also be because of the circular import errors you get when packages import each other, for example. But good to know it's at least not totally unfamiliar. By exiting the condition correctly you mean like for example keeping track of the parents you already processed

Comment: yes but there is complexity with bidirectional relationships  - which comes from managing updates to them since often both sides will need to be maintained in response to any change in a transaction-like operation - if you can manage that then theoretically for any child of `parents`, `getchildren(child.parents)`  _should_ always be the same as the `parents.children`.